# UISearchController with IBOutlet UISearchbar

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to use IBOutlet UISearchbar for tableView Search
Below is the code

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()   
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar //not this way
        //IBSearchBar = controller.searchBar (this is a IBOutlet Searchbar which I wanted to use instead of adding search bar from program)
        return controller
    })()
```

I am following this URL :http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift and trying to implement using my seachbar from interface builder.

when I add searchbar programmatically it works fine, all delegate methods are called, but if I try to set up with IBSearchBar delegate method is not called.

Please suggest.